# Flutter - Show a floating widget when list scrolls down

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

Is there a way to show a floating widget in top of the screen when list is scrolled up?

I have a widget (inside a scrollable widget) in my screen, when I scroll up, I want to convert this widget to a sticky header. and put it back when I scroll down.

I have tried using Slivers and SliverAppBar (if floating is set to true), but it works the other way around, it shows up when scrolling down and hides when scrolling otherwise.

Any idea where to look? or any example?

Here is what I tried.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 100,
      ),
    ),

    // I wan to stick this widget in the top, when I scroll up, initially it should be gone. 
    SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      floating: true,
      expandedHeight: 70,
      flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text("Sticky Header"),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
        return Text("Text $index");
      }, childCount: 50),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image: here is what I'm trying to do.]

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @AR see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an existing Flutter package that would meet your requirements. Try to check [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers/example).

> Lets you place headers on scrollable content that will stick to the
> top of the container whilst the content is scrolled.

See also: [flutter_sticky_header](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header)